# Facebook Style Newsfeed Image Mosaic View for iOS?

Tags: ios

I want to achieve a similar look and feel to the Facebook app's newsfeed image mosaic (see below screenshot). Does anyone know of an existing library/pod which will achieve this, or suggestions on the best approach to achieving this (custom UIView vs UICollectionView)?

My requirements are:

- If there is a single image, then just show it as per the left example below. The view should respect the aspect ratio.
- If there are 2 or more images then present draw a suitable view as per the right image, which again respects image aspect and calculates the size/position for 2 images, 3 images or 4 images.
- Images should be tappable.
- Works within a UITableViewCell, including auto layout calculations etc.

I haven't seen anything like this out there yet, in code form at least. Any pointers would be greatly appreciated :)

[image: Left: Single Image presentation format, Right: Multiple image presentation format]

Comment: Check the following https://github.com/betzerra/MosaicUI

Comment: Visually that is what I am looking for, however technically the library has a few limitations in the approach when loading images over the wire. A good starting point I'll investigate further to extend for my use case.